# Why am I being asked to enter a Parameter value? MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

```
SELECT DNAME, COUNT(*) AS TotalPerDep
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E, Department AS D
WHERE D.DNUMBER = E.DNO
GROUP BY D.DName
HAVING SUM(TotalPerDep) <4;
```

I am not sure why this prompts me to enter a parameter value. If I remove the HAVING portion it works just fine.

Comment: Please share table structure and sample data so that we can recreate the scenario.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1):

There is no column named **TotalPerDep**. You can not use SUM() in having clause on alias this way. Do you just want Having count(*)<4 instead?  please share your sample data and desired output to let me help you finding your solution.

```
SELECT DNAME, COUNT(*) AS TotalPerDep
FROM EMPLOYEE AS E, Department AS D
WHERE D.DNUMBER = E.DNO
GROUP BY D.DName
HAVING count(*) <4;
```

Comment: Thank you, that is all that needed to find my solution. I appreciate your time.